# Should keys represented with <kbd> tags be always uppercase?

Tags: discussion, formatting

##### Should keys represented with <kbd> tags be always uppercase?

In [this edit to "Delete from cursor to end of line in `vi`"](https://unix.stackexchange.com/posts/4416/revisions) <kbd>d</kbd><kbd>$</kbd> was changed into <kbd>D</kbd><kbd>$</kbd>. I thought the answer was incorrect since `d` and `D` commands are different in Vi; I had to read the edit note by AdminBee to understand the reason for the change, namely

> Keys are labelled uppercase, so "uppercase D" should be "Shift"-"D" in  tags.

Although it makes sense, I think it does more harm than good. I want to roll it back, but first I'd like to invite more opinions.

Comment: Isn't the capitalization critical here? The comments say "shift-D is a synonym for d$".

Comment: Not all keyboards have uppercase letters, not even all physical keyboards.

Comment: Following that reasoning, the suggested `D` `$` should really be `D` `shift-4`, which would be very difficult to argue as a better idea than `d` `$`.

Comment: @RayButterworth, but shift-4 gives the € sign... well, on my keyboard layout it does :) Especially for special characters one shouldn't assume their placement

Answer (score 15):

In this case, definitely no. In particular, showing a command as <kbd>D</kbd><kbd>W</kbd> is misleading; `D` already does something different than `dw`.

Also, vi is a terminal program, it doesn't see keypresses as such, only *characters*. It doesn't care if you use Caps Lock instead of Shift to get the uppercase `D`, so presenting the command as <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd> is beside the point too.

I took the liberty of [editing the answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/posts/4416/revisions). The original didn't have the <kbd> tags either.

That said, I would write `^D` `Ctrl-D` <kbd>Ctrl+D</kbd> <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd> and such with an uppercase D, because uppercase letters are somewhat easier to tell apart, and I think it's commonly understood that something like that doesn't involve Shift.
Also I'm pretty sure Caps Lock doesn't usually affect that use.

<sub>(Of course someone could make weirder changes to their keymap, as in arrange for <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd> to send a `^Z` instead, but that's likely to be rather unusual.)</sub>

Comment: "*I think it's commonly understood that something like that doesn't involve Shift*".
I agree, but there's one nit-picky technical complication though (anyone knowledgeable enough to run into it will quickly figure it out).
`[ctrl-U]0e3f` can be used to enter Thailand's bhat currency sign, "฿", but an unshifted `[ctrl-u]` will (in VI) delete everything up to the current cursor.
In that case: `shift` + `ctrl-U` should be used to make the required shift obvious.

Answer (score 9):

> Should keys represented with <kbd> tags be always uppercase?

No — they should probably represent the exact case that is needed for the function. Where it could be confusing (<kbd>i</kbd> vs <kbd>I</kbd> vs <kbd>l</kbd> vs <kbd>L</kbd> and <kbd>o</kbd> vs <kbd>O</kbd> vs <kbd>0</kbd>), it might be worth a parenthetical to spell out the letter.

Answer (score 9):

I agree with [@ilkkachu's answer](https://unix.meta.stackexchange.com/a/5811/377345) that in this case, the [original typesetting](https://unix.stackexchange.com/revisions/4416/2) of the answer using "code" formatting rather than "keystrokes" makes more sense, and my edit should probably have been to revert to that typesetting. Still, we need to find a consistent style on how to represent keystrokes.

I have the impression (but cannot back it up with statistical evidence) that a widely accepted convention - which in particular novices will have often seen - is that a key combination statement written as <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> means to press the "Control" key and then the "c" key *without* shift, and if a "Shift" key were needed, write this as <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>, and that this is the case because on many keyboards, the keys *are* labelled upper-case. So, I would vote in favor of this representation *when expressing key combinations as used in keyboard shortcuts*, but not when it comes to entering commands on text entry prompts as in `vi` or `less`.

A similar problem is the representation of "key strokes" vs. "key chords", i.e. how to distinguish a key combination where the keys have to be pressed simultaneously (or the later ones at least while the former ones are still down) from a combination where one of the keys has to be released before the later keys are pressed. One could think about using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>**-**<kbd>X</kbd> to mean one thing and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>**+**<kbd>X</kbd> to mean the other thing, but again a consensus is needed for which means which.

Or, we could opt to remove the keystroke typesetting altogether and adopt the notation used in the Emacs documentation (although - as also noted by @Quasimodo in a comment - it is not easy to understand for people inexperienced with Emacs, which likely make up a majority of possible readers).

Comment: §2: I also have that impression. I can see that Ctrl+X and Ctrl+Shift+X notation on Firefox and GIMP menu bars too. $3 I think the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>X</kbd> suggestion harms readability, especially when there are lots of keys, and typing those tags are a true pain on itself. §4 I think Emacs' notation is the best, but certainly a bunch of people unacquainted with it would be confused (the "oh, `C-x`... that must be (shift) c hyphen x" sort of mistake).

Comment: About "key chords": `<kbd>` can be nested, see how it looks in [one of my answers on SU](https://superuser.com/a/1560646/432690).

Comment: As a non-emacs user, what is the notation to which you're referring?

Comment: @roaima the same notation as is used in bash’s readline documentation ;-). `C-x` for Ctrl+X, `M-y` for Meta+Y etc.

Comment: My understanding and experience with most documentation I have seen for the purposes of distinguishing chords from sequences is that `+` and `-` are interchangeable and represent chords (e. g. `Ctrl`-`A` for `screen`'s escape character, while `,` represents an unchorded sequence, e. g. `Ctrl-A`, `d` or `^A`, `d` for the sequence to disconnect a `screen` session).